# Why the use of PhoneGap in mobile app while HTML5 supports Geo Location?

Tags: html, geolocation, cordova

I am currently developing a mobile app which need the current position of the user and runs in the browser. 
I have done some searches and I found people recommend PhoneGap. I am wondering why I can't use the Geo location of the browser since most browsers now support the HMTL5 specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can use geolocation in mobile apps. People suggest to use phonegap because it can give much more control on the device features than a normal web app. These include
Hardware specific features supported by the PhoneGap API include:

**Geolocation**

**Vibration**

**Accelerometer**

**Sound**

and more..

Plus it is supported on 7 platforms. You can create cross platform app just mastering html5, js, etc. if anything is not supported by phonegap then you can use a native plugin for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap offers more than just Geolocation - e.g. access to contacts, accelerometers, camera etc. In fact, by default Phonegap apps use the HTML5 geolocation API anyway though you can override this to use the native implementation.